# Declaring a Brushes variable for input

Tags: c#, graphics, colors, bitmap

I currently have the following method

```
public void printTitle(string title){
    // settings for stringformat
    g.DrawString(title, drawFontTitle, Brushes.White, x, y, stringFormatTitle);
}
```

However, I am trying to let the input define the color of the title, like so:

```
public void printTitle(string title, Brushes titleColor){
    // settings for stringformat
    g.DrawString(title, drawFontTitle, titleColor, x, y, stringFormatTitle);
}
```

And it would be used like this:

`printTitle("Title Text", Brushes.White);`

However, I think there is an issue when declaring the `Brushes titleColor` that's causing an error.

Comment: You (and everybody else) can see who edited what bij clicking the ['edited... ago'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192097/revisions) link next to your name. So there is no need to add thanks and other noise.. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are passing the value of `Brushes.Color` which is of type brush and your method has Brushes as the parameter type:

```
public void printTitle(string title, Brushes titleColor)
{
    // settings for stringformat
    g.DrawString(title, drawFontTitle, titleColor, x, y, stringFormatTitle);
}
```

So use this instead it will work:

```
public void printTitle(string title, Brush titleColor)
{
    // settings for stringformat
    g.DrawString(title, drawFontTitle, titleColor, x, y, stringFormatTitle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. I also formatted your code so it's more readable, but the edit didn't make it through..